# Does anyone know how to remove the wires from this light socket, does anyone know how I find information about this type of socket?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, light, socket

[image]

The socket is from a wall mounted light fixture, the side of the socket says AI YACHT AT578 4/250. I've tried googling this product information but all I get is advertisements for yachts. Does anyone know how to find information about this product and also how to remove the wires from the socket. I need to repair the light fixture and in order to put it back on the wall I need to remove this light socket.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Are those wires supposed to be removable? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just remove it at the terminal blocks visible in the background? You may have to pull them out of the wall.

These are single-use "backstab" connections.  The wire can be removed either by firm pulling or jabbing a screwdriver in the slot release there, but then, the spring will be damaged and will no longer hold reliably. You would need to replace the socket at that point.

Comment: I think that is only an earth terminal. Do you know how to find out where I can buy one of these sockets?